# Removing SQL Server CE

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I have a web app I've been using with SQL Server CE so far, recently we've decided to migrate to standard SQL Server and add a login. In order to do this, I created a new project with the default ASP.Net login and copied most of the files over.

The project has a Data project, which contains the standard code first stuff: a context, migrations, entities. As part of the copy I scrubbed all references to SQL Server CE, including all the dependencies of the projects and nuget.

The database queries relating to the pre-built login system work; when something in the Data project runs however, I get this:

> Schema specified is not valid.
>
> Errors: (0,0) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I've done a search over every single file in Sublime and SQL Server CE does not appear, nor does compact and nor does sqlce. There should be no knowledge that it ever used SQL Server CE in a previous life.

Strangely, some of the migrations have run; the one it fails on looks like any other, creating a table. If I try to run the migrations in the package manager console, I get the same error.

I've tried absolutely everything to remove all references to SQL Server CE, but this error is very persistent. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Did you look in the EDMX file?

Comment: @ErikEJ I don't have one, it's completely code first.

Comment: Migrations resource files? Feel free to share a repro project privately